# Obtaining specific csv cell data using import csv

Tags: python, csv, import

So I am having difficulties. I am trying to establish a local database using python, but with as little user input as possible. I have a script that makes csv files with specific headers {id, name, details} and a script that will retrieve specific rows as needed.

```
import csv
ID = input("Input ID Number  :")
File_Name = str(ID)+str(".csv")
with open(File_Name, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    rows = list(reader)
    print(rows[1])
```

Assume that the File_Name exists, and the goal is to obtain the data in Row 2 Column 2. This data will be used to further append the file later :)

Question: How would I go further from here to obtain the data in the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
ID = input("Input ID Number  :")
File_Name = str(ID)+ ".csv"
with open(File_Name, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    rows = list(reader)
    print(rows[1][1])
```

---

```
12 09 022
14 15 212
```

---

```
15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read specific cell with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

id_ = input('Input ID Number: ')
df = pd.read_csv('{}.csv'.format(id_), header=None, delimiter=' ')
print(df.iat[1, 1])
```

Let's say we have following `file.csv`:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Result will be:

```
Input ID Number: file
5
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ended up taking

column = rows[1] to get the second column value from the array. Thank you all